# UML Class Diagram: Third Party Software Inheritance

Tags: inheritance, uml, class-diagram

I have an application with several classes that inherit/are subclass from third party library classes. Example, QDialog from Qt Framework.

Should I specify that inheritance relationship in the UML class diagrams of my application?

Is expect (or is it standard) to represent such relationships?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the readership. If they know the domain, you can probably leave it out. However, you should create some context diagram for each class. And that context diagram should show the inheritance. This way you can serve all kind of readers.